# SVG animate fill to none results in black background

Tags: svg, jquery-animate, svg-animate, smil

I would expect this to animate to a transparent background. Any idea why it animates to black or how to fix it?

```
<svg>
  <rect height="100" width="100">
    <animate attributeName="fill" from="red" to="none" dur="3s" fill="freeze">
  </rect>
</svg>
```

Related CodePen: http://codepen.io/corysimmons/pen/Byeoyw?editors=100

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured it out below.

Answer (score 1):

`none` isn't valid. `transparent` works as expected.